# How to fetch the image in ms word from web application which is given as a link?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

Scenario :
I have an option for generating report(with text and image contents) in my application, that can be viewed in web format and also in Ms word.

In Word, the image which is in the report is a link. here the situation is, even if i remove the link, the image should get visible(in my case it is not).

My question is, how to fetch the image into the word document, so it can be viewed even if we remove the link of it.

For generating ms word report im using - "Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");"

Answer (score 0):

-Go to Insert - Quick Parts - Field...

In Field Names, select "IncludePicture".

In the field "Filename or URL", put the URL to your image.

UnCheck "Data not stored in document".

And eventually the 2 "Resize..." checkboxes if the size of the online image can change.

Comment: But what i intented to say is, tat im not going to change or edit in  ms word. But when i generating the report itself, the image in it should be fetched in ms word, so even if i change the url inside the application later, it should not get affected..